# Deny access to all content except content from one folder

Tags: apache, security

I want to allow access to only one folder of my site in a given subdomain, and have another subdomain pointing to same documentRoot with full access. I want this to avoid duplicated urls (for SEO purposes).

In the restricted virtualHost I have this configuration ...

```
    <Directory /var/www/secundary.mysite.com/web>
    Options -Includes +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !/bundles.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
    </Directory>
```

So I expect that navigation to mysite.com give a forbidden response, but www.mysite.com/bundles/js/script.js returns a normal response.

The result is that every request to secundary.mysite.com returns a normal response. Am I missing something, or ...?

Comment: I mean ... " I expect that navigation to secundary.mysite.com give a forbidden response, but secundary.mysite.com/bundles/js/script.js"

Comment: Why do you use the rewriting module for this? Isn't a simple "Deny from all" more suitable?

Comment: Ok, but I don't know then how to allow access to "bundles" directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using a wrong variable. I wrote %{QUERY_STRING} instead %{REQUEST_URI} that was the variable that I wanted to match again the regular expression. The correct syntax for my purpose was:

```
<Directory /var/www/secundary.mysite.com/web>
Options -Includes +ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bundles(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
</Directory>
```